# Bitmap from url without scaling

Tags: android

i am getting bitamap from a url. Everything is fine but i m having small issue i.e my bitmap from url gets scales down. I want bitmap of original size without scaling. How to achieve this. I tried options but no success yet. here is my code:

```
try {
URL url = new URL(src);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
```

I set this drawable to imagview. But image is scaled down. I want original size and original size is not too big so need to worry about outofmemory exception. Is there any way to avoid scaling while parsing bitmap from url stream.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly show image from web without downloading it. Please check the below function . It will show the images from the web into your image view.

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

then set image to imageview using code in your activity. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: thanks. Why didn't i think of this at first ? :D Thanks again

Comment: you are in loop that time, so thats why you never think of this one option... :)

Comment: but this results in a Drawable, not a Bitmap